# Function to set image of buttons causes image to jump between buttons

Tags: image, button, tkinter

I'm trying to teach myself the tkinter module by programming minesweeper. I have created a grid with buttons and a method to set an image flag to cells. It works, in that when you press the right mouse button the image of the button changes as desired, but when you right click on the next button the image just moves to the next button, rather than creating a second flag. I want to be able to place a new flag image on each cell that I right click, rather than just shuffle the image around. Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as Tk


def main():
   root = Tk.Tk()
   root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(700, 700))
   instance = Minesweeper(root, 10, 10)
   root.mainloop()


class Minesweeper:

    def __init__(self, parent, height, width):

        self.top_frame = Tk.Frame(parent)
        self.top_frame.place(anchor=Tk.CENTER, relx=0.5, rely=0.5)
        self.frames = []
        self.buttons = []
        index = 0

        for x in range(height):
            for y in range(width):
                self.frames.append(Tk.Frame(self.top_frame, height=50, width=50))
                self.buttons.append(Tk.Button(self.frames[index], bg="white"))
                self.frames[index].grid_propagate(False)
                self.frames[index].columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
                self.frames[index].rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
                self.frames[index].grid(row=x, column=y)
                self.buttons[index].grid(sticky="wens")
                self.buttons[index].bind('<Button-3>', self.flag)
                index += 1

    def flag(self, event):
        self.flag = Tk.PhotoImage(file="flag.png")
        event.widget.configure(image=self.flag)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the below fixed it:

```
def flag(self, event):
    self.flag = Tk.PhotoImage(file="flag.png")
    event.widget.image = self.flag     # <---- this seemed to fix it
    event.widget.configure(image=self.flag)
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you did more than just post code. Can you explain what you did and why it was necessary?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, sadly I'm not really sure why it was necessary. I think it has something to do with garbage collection but I don't fully understand.